# Is it good if a table have single index and composite index on same field?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INT NOT NULL,
last_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY `first_name` (first_name),
KEY `last_name` (last_name),
KEY `last_first` (last_name,first_name)
);
```

Is it good if a table have single index and composite index on same field if i have queries like :

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name = 'A';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name= 'A';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name= 'A' AND first_name = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr Answer:** Test it. The answer largely depends on your data and your queries, so we cannot give a definitive answer that holds for all scenarios. As long as you haven't tested it, don't use the additional composite index. It smells like premature optimization.

A composite index---in comparison to having only the single-row indexes---*can* speed things up. Your last query *could* be sped up by it. Let me start by digging a bit deeper into the inner workings of your database.

### Using composite indexes in query processing

A composite index would allow to perform a single *index scan* for your third query to quickly find all matching tuples. I.e., the DBMS simply asks the index "give me all tuples that match the two predicates". The composite index is able to determine this quickly.

In contrast, if you would only have the non-composite indexes, no such scan could be made. Instead, your RDBMS would have two choices to answer your query:

1. Perform a so-called index intersection: Look up matching tuples in both indexes and then compute the intersection
2. Use only one of the indexes and use the second predicate to filter the output

I am not sure which of these strategies would be performed by MySQL. Check the generated plan to be sure.

### Is there a speed up?

As mentioned above, if you have the composite index, your RDBMS has three possibilities to process the third query:

1. A single index scan on the composite index
2. Index intersection of the single-row indexes
3. Usage of one index and filter tuples using second predicate

Now, to give you an answer whether a composite index can speed things up, we have to determine which of these ways is the fastest. Short answer: **It depends on the data**. *Yes, there is a good chance that the index scan of the composite index is the fastest.* But the question is how much faster is it? Because an additional index is expensive, only a really noticeable speedup would justify an extra composite index.

Especially the selectivity of your predicates determines whether the composite index is worth it. For example, consider that 90% of all tuples satisfy `last_name= 'A'` (i.e., the selectivity of this predicate is low). Then, the composite index would be very superfluous. Simply using way (3), i.e., filtering on the predicate without using an index in your last query would be equally fast than a composite index scan. The second solution would be slowest, as the intersection result is pretty large.

But now consider that only 0.00001% of all tuples satisfy the predicate. Then, (1) would have huge benefits over (3) because it only selects matching tuples while (3) selects a lot of tuples and then filters most of them out (because they do not match the predicate). (2) would be the second fastest solution in this case (as the intersection size is pretty small) but it would not be as fast as the composite scan, as building an intersection is always a bit costly (intersection can be done by using a hash join, for example).

**In conclusion, how big the speedup of the composite index is depends on the data and the predicates you use. So, you have to test it. We cannot give a precise answer here.**

It also depends on how clever your optimizer is. So it might change when you update your MySQL since the optimizer might have changed and now choose a better (or worse) strategy to process your query.

### What are the drawbacks of an additional composite index?

An additional index costs two things:

1. Space, of course.
2. Update time: The index must be kept up to date so insertions, deletions, and updates that alter the indexed columns get slower. If you have a lot of updates, the additional index may even reduce your overall performance.

### When should you use the additional composite index?

As shown above, an additional index has costs but may speed up queries. Here are some heuristics when to use an additional composite index:

1. You have many queries that really use both columns (for all other queries, the additional index yields no benefit)
2. The predicates in these queries are highly selective
3. You have enough space, i.e., paying space for the additional index won't hurt you
4. Your data is not too dynamic, i.e., you have few updates but many more queries, so updating the additional index won't hurt you.

**However, the best answer when to use it would be the following IMHO:**

See an additional composite index as a form of optimization. So the famous rule applies: *"The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet."*

Only perform this optimization after you have identified multi-column queries to be the bottleneck of your application. Measure the difference. If there is a considerable one, keep the index, otherwise drop it.

Comment: ehm ok 
so is it not a redundant if make single and composite index like that ?

Comment: @reza_daulay: No, not completely reduntant, i.e., there are queries that can benefit from the extra composite index. However, it is doubtable whether this benefit is large enough to justify the extra index.

Answer (score 0):

Because the typical range of values of names is large, especially so for last names, the filtering is already dramatic with simple indexes. The improvement gained by a composite index would be minimal, probably not measurable and may even yield *worse* performance due there being less index entires per I/O page (the entries being roughly twice the size) and updates will slow slightly too the more indexes there are to maintain.

**Just use individual indexes on each column and let the optimizer do the rest.**

If you have string evidence that there's a performance problem directly attributable to the lack of a composite index, only then consider it and experiment.